# Pandas Python, select columns based on rows conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4))
print(df)
          0         1         2         3
0  1.489198  1.329603  1.590124  1.123505
1  0.024017  0.581033  2.500397  0.156280
```

I want to select the columns which for there is at least one row with a value greater than `2`. I tried the following, but it did not work as expected.

```
df[df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2]]
```

In this toy example my expected output would be:

```
       2
1.590124  
2.500397
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt) and `any` to filter the df:

```
In [287]:
df.ix[:,df.gt(2).any()]

Out[287]:
          2
0  1.590124
1  2.500397
```

Here we use `ix` to select all rows, the first `:` and the next arg is a boolean mask of the columns that meet the condition:

```
In [288]:
df.gt(2)

Out[288]:
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False

In [289]:
df.gt(2).any()

Out[289]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

In your example what you did was select the cell value for the first row and second column, you then tried to use this to mask the columns but this just returned the first column hence why it didn't work:

```
In [291]:
df.iloc[(0,1)]

Out[291]:
1.3296030000000001

In [293]:
df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2]

Out[293]:
'0'
```

Comment: Ok thkx to both of you, anyone knows what my script is supposed to do?

Comment: this `df.iloc[(0,1)]` selected the first row and second column cell value and tested if it was greater than 2 which it's not so it won't work

Comment: thk you EdChum for your answer

Comment: EdChum, what if I want to select columns which for at least one row is LOWER than a specific value or is EQUAL to a specific value? Or how to reverse a dataframe of boolean entries?

Comment: use `le` or `<=` if you prefer

Answer (score 3):

Use `mask` created with `df > 2` with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and then select columns by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(18)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4))
print(df)
          0         1         2         3
0  0.079428  2.190202 -0.134892  0.160518
1  0.442698  0.623391  1.008903  0.394249

print ((df>2).any())
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

print (df.ix[:, (df>2).any()])
          1
0  2.190202
1  0.623391
```

EDIT by comment:

You can check your solution per partes:

It seems it works, but it always select second column (`1`, python count from `0`) column if condition `True`:

```
print (df.iloc[(0,1)])
2.19020235741

print (df.iloc[(0,1)] > 2)
True

print (df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2])
1

print (df[df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2]])
0    2.190202
1    0.623391
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

And first column (`0`) column if `False`, because boolean `True` and `False` are casted to `1` and `0`:

```
np.random.seed(15)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4))
print (df)
          0         1         2         3
0 -0.312328  0.339285 -0.155909 -0.501790
1  0.235569 -1.763605 -1.095862 -1.087766

print (df.iloc[(0,1)])
0.339284706046

print (df.iloc[(0,1)] > 2)
False

print (df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2])
0

print (df[df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2]])
0   -0.312328
1    0.235569
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

If change column names:

```
np.random.seed(15)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 4))
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
print (df)
          a         b         c         d
0 -0.312328  0.339285 -0.155909 -0.501790
1  0.235569 -1.763605 -1.095862 -1.087766

print (df.iloc[(0,1)] > 2)
False

print (df[df.columns[df.iloc[(0,1)]>2]])
0   -0.312328
1    0.235569
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ok thkx to both of you, anyone knows what my script is supposed to do?

Comment: I try explain it by samples, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Quick update, as `.ix` is now deprecated (since `0.20.0`). For lastest versions of pandas, `.loc` will do the trick:

```
df.loc[:, df.gt(2).any()]
```